# Joining on a TVF that builds a temp table is much faster than straight clause. Why is this?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

We were optimising a query that looked to be poorly designed. There was a join to a multi-line table valued function, that could easily have been an inline function, so we updated it.. but the query became much slower. The multi-line function was returning a temp table with a single column as the primary key, while the inline TVF just returned a straight single column table.

Doing a bit of R&D, we found that there were big performance gains using joined multi-line TVFs as clauses. The following example can be run against any DB, preferably with a long history of object updates. The first query is what we thought would be the best design, but it is the second that performs far better (typically 20x faster). *This was actually query cost, not speed*

```
create function udf_ObjectsModifiedBetweenDates
(
    @DateFrom datetime,
    @Dateto datetime
)
returns @t table(object_id int primary key)
as
begin
insert into @t
(
    object_id
)
select object_id
from sys.objects 
where modify_date between @DateFrom and @Dateto
return
end

GO

declare @datefrom datetime = '2017-05-01' --Please adjust these dates to get good sample
declare @dateto datetime = '2018-08-02'

--slow
select object_id, parent_object_id, is_ms_shipped
from sys.objects
where modify_date between @datefrom and @dateto option (recompile)

--fast
select o.object_id, o.parent_object_id, o.is_ms_shipped
from sys.objects o
inner join udf_ObjectsModifiedBetweenDates(@datefrom, @dateto) ombd on o.object_id = ombd.object_id option (recompile)
```

The function and query is similar to the one that we were dealing with on our system, but here we have substituted a system table for the user table. We have tried the same thing on other user tables, again getting huge benefit from the MTVF.
The execution plans show that there is a clustered index scan on the TVF on the faster query.
Can anyone explain what is happening and if this is a viable method to improve query performance?

[image]

Comment: I'm finding quite the opposite, the query without the udf ran in 61ms (returning 19305 rows). The udf query ran in 323ms. This is also what I would have expected. Multi-line Table-value functions are generally (big) performance hitters.

Comment: @Larnu I have added the execution plans for both queries run together. We have tempdb on a separate drive and using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)    on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) ..NOT 2012 as tagged, but same results on a different 2012 server.

Comment: Execution plan doesn't mean speed. They are completely different things. I too, have a "98%" cost for the first query, however, that doesn't change the fact is it 5 times faster. You can get the time is takes to compete a query by using `SET STATISTICS TIME ON;`. If you inspect the times, you'll probably see that the query without the UDF is by far the better choice.

Comment: The UDF chocie is also far worse on  IO. The IO for my queries was `Scan count 1, logical reads 379` for the non UDF, and `Scan count 0, logical reads 38610` + `Scan count 1, logical reads 34` for the UDF. That is **horrifically** worse. (You can see IO stats by using `SET STATISTICS IO ON;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are misinterpreting "Query cost (relative to the batch)" for "Query cost (how long the query will take to run)" in the execution plan. The cost of a query can have very little to do with how efficient or fast a query is.

I ran this query (changing the dates) with both the following on:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
```

For the query you labeled as "slow" (the one without the UDF) the result was:

```
The "slow" one

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 8 ms, elapsed time = 8 ms.

(19305 rows affected)
Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 379, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 62 ms,  elapsed time = 61 ms.
```

And for the one you labeled "fast" (The UDF) the output was:

```
The "fast" one

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 7 ms.

(19305 rows affected)
Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 0, logical reads 38610, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#B1BBD6DD'. Scan count 1, logical reads 34, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 266 ms,  elapsed time = 329 ms.
```

As you can see by these stats, the non-UDF version was by far the winner. The execution time for the non-UDF was more than 5 times faster, however, the IO for the UDF query was insane (over 1,000 times more reads).

In all honesty, Multi-line Table-Value Functions are more than often performance killers. Of the 3 types of functions (inline table-value, Scalar value and multi-line table-value) they are probably the slowest, where as inline are by far often the faster. I have heard, on the rumour mill, that scalar functions are "better" in SQL Server 2019, however, I haven't tested myself nor have i actually seen any real evidence yet; just in conversation.

Comment: Yes That is what I was doing. In that case, what is the use of: 'Query cost (relative to the batch)'?

Comment: @cloudsafe last I heard it was Microsoft speak for *"We haven't the foggiest idea, so here's some numbers which can be highly mis-informative."*